# scope of object allocated to vectors?

Tags: c++, scope, undefined

I the below code , could you please tell if the scope of point object in function getObjects() is valid or not.
I am creating object in createObj() , so scope of object "p" is limited to createObj()....does vector take care of this using copy constructor ?

```
void getObjects()
{
    vector<point> vec;
    creatObj(vec);
    // getting correct output for object allocated in vector vec.
}

void createObj(vector<point> &vec)
{
    point p;
    p.x=10;
    p.y=20;
    vec.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: did not get it..please explain with example

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought the parameter was what was being pushed onto the vector for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

It's all good, as the `push_back` call in `createObj` creates a *copy*.

Comment: I was looking at:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/. The site mentions "The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element". What does `move` mean here. I understand the value "copied" or "moved" are not semantically same.

Comment: If it moves, then all pointers attached to it before becomes invalid?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam See [What are move semantics?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/395760)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not passing a pointer into the vector, you're safe. If you were passing in a pointer, you would need to ensure that what the pointer points to remains valid as long as you needed it.

Comment: you mean to say if i allocate point object memory in heap and store the pointer in vector object.
i guess it still be valid , if i don't delete objects allocated in the vector ??

Comment: Yes, your objects in the heap will have their contents preserved after the function call terminates, and the pointers to them (which you copied into your vector) are still valid pointers because of this (until you delete the objects, of course).

Comment: even if delete say object x (which takes input point *p=new point() )...... now after delete if i iterate the vector ..will it cause me any trouble???... if yes then how can i avoid it

Comment: Iterating the contents of the vector will not directly be a problem, but using the pointers that are no longer valid will!). To avoid this, you might want to never directly allocate your new objects, but instead provide your own functions... one to "allocate and push to vector", and another to "remove from vector and delete". If you don't/can't manage like this, then you must be very careful. Some language/runtimes (like ObjectiveC) make this easier for you, but C++ requires you to take more care.

Comment: @Mah: Nope, C++ does it for you too. Use a smart pointer, not `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @mah : could you please provide an example or tutorial link for the method you have suggested ?

Comment: I don't know of a particular tutorial but I would suggest you google for "smart pointer c++" to follow up with @LightnessRacesinOrbit 's suggestion.

Comment: No, do not "google for tutorials". Obtain a quality, peer-reviewed C++ book. http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648